# CASTING to NUMERIC or DECIMAL results in SQL0802 Error (Can not move down to next row in dataset)

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

Here is the SQL that is generating the error:

```
when evecpt LIKE '%T006%' OR evesrv LIKE '%T006%' then CAST ('.25' AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```

Comment: What operating system runs your Db2-server (z/OS, i-series , Linux/Unix/Windows)?   What Db2-version?

Comment: The server is iSeries

Comment: Always tag your Db2 questions with the correct platform designator because answers depend on that.  ALSO, what is the i-series *version* ?

Comment: I'm not sure of the version.  Is there a command I can run to view it?

Comment: What is the rest of the case statement, you might have an another when or else that is generating the error.  That cast statement works on our system at 7.1.  One place you can see the os version is on the header of a job log - ours shows V7R1M0.

Comment: @JobbieDaddy Can you provide some reproducible example? Like `select case when evecpt LIKE '%T006%' OR evesrv LIKE '%T006%' then CAST ('.25' AS DECIMAL(10,2)) end from table(values (?, ?) [... , (?, ?)]) t (evecpt, evesrv)`